# Allow variable in regex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow my variable to be a part of regex.
For instance:

```
const delimiter = '.';
```

I want to to use it like this:

```
someString
  .replace(/[^0-9{delimiter}-]/g, '')
  .replace(/(\.{delimiter}*)\./g, '$1')
  .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
```

instead of

```
someString
  .replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')
  .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
  .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
```

How to achieve this?
Actually, the reason why it's needed it to remove all non-numeric and non-decimal symbols from the given string. The issue is the format delimiter in different locales, so the delimiter can be `.` or `,` depending on the localization.

UPD: I saw that my question is duplicated, but in the original answer the example is pretty simple and gives me nothing.
Especially, I don't understand how to split `/[^0-9.-]/g` to `/[^0-9` and `-]/g` to put my variable in between.

Comment: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, how to split /[^0-9.-]/g to /[^0-9 + delimiter + -]/g correctly?